# java.lang.NoClassDeffoundError when attempting to use FileFilter

Tags: filefilter

My application works on my laptop, but when I attempt to run the app that uses the code for `FileFilter` I get the `NoClassDeffoundError` on a production machine. my version is 1.8.0.201 and the prod machine is 1.8.0.121.

```
FileFilter dirFilter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;   
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please, add more specifications about the error.

Comment: Hello. Some java class is missing, but without details, we cannot help you much. You may have a look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java